# Getting layout coordinates of graph vertices using python, networkx, pygraphviz

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz, graph-layout

I want to create a graph using NetworkX, layout the graph using Graphviz(via pygraphviz). I have successfully ran all the examples in the [NetworkX pygraphviz examples documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/examples/pygraphviz/index.html)

The question I have is - how do I get the coordinates (x, y) and dimensions (width, height) of the vertices back into the NetworkX graph.
That is the goal. I want only Graphviz' layout capabilities, not drawing capabilities. Is that possible using this stack (NetworkX, pygraphviz, graphviz)? Any other way?

The background motivation is this.
Graphviz outputs png, or ps, or svg and many other formats.
But I don't want to be constrained by the formats Graphviz handles. 
And I want to be able to post-process the layout results, even 
if I end up outputting the popular formats like Graphviz does support.

**Update**: I have rewritten the question for clarity. The advice on Graphviz output formats miss the point. It is the layout data that I need

**Update2**: One suggestion was to make Graphviz ouptput in some format that I can then parse the layout data back from. The suggestion was for SVG. 
I had had considered that possibility. Graphviz outputs json (according to [Graphviz output formats documentation page](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:json0)). I failed to make it work on my windows installation - for some reason not all the output formats were present). However it is the approach that makes me uneasy. Parsing formatted output for data that was used to create that output seems backwards. The data itself should have been made available, I think.

**Update 3** - There is a similar question - 
[How to get the coordinates from layout from graphviz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938770/how-to-get-the-coordinates-from-layout-from-graphviz). One of the answers suggests using NetworkX. However the answer uses layout made by NetworkX and not Graphviz. The author of the answer did not know how to get the Graphviz layout data. So my question remains relevant, and yet to be answered

**Update 4** - it is 07-2019 and I still did not find a way to solve this. I marked one answer as accepted - but with a caveat - I still am in the dark despite the good advice found in that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael, I re-read your question and comments and with the tools I know that work (and I know how to use), this is what I'd do in your shoes.  I  would draw your charts in DOT/GraphViz and then choose a human-readable and easy-to-parse format such as SVG, "plain", or even x-dot.   Why?  Not to get the graph itself  -- some of these don't even realize graphs -- but because these formats are **human-readable and contain the X-Y coordinates of the different drawing components**.  You can use those coordinates and sizes to your own purposes.  Some snips from a simple graph I just did should illustrate.  SVG first

```
<svg width="89pt" height="188pt"

<g id="node1" class="node"><title>A</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="54" cy="-162" rx="27" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="54" y="-158.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">A</text>
```

Or in "plain" format, perhaps simplest for parsing:

```
graph 1 0.75 1.5
node A 0.375 1.25 0.75 0.5 A solid ellipse black lightgrey
node B 0.375 0.25 0.75 0.5 B solid ellipse black lightgrey
edge A B 4 0.375 0.99579 0.375 0.88865 0.375 0.7599 0.375 0.64045 solid black
stop
```

Or VML which is html-like:

```
<v:oval style="position:absolute; left: 0.00; top: 0.00; width: 54.00; height: 36.00" filled="false"  >
```

Etc... Not hard to imagine parsing out all the X-Ys of the various elements and repurposing them as you see fit.

Comment: JLH, I know SVG well. Graphviz outputs SVG too. I however want to get the layout data (x,y, width, height of nodes) not the output format of any kind. I'll take care of the output myself. It is the layout logic that  I don't want to deal with. I thought that I made my desired functionality clear in the question. I am mistaken. I'll correct the question

Comment: JLH, re-reading your answer, I realized that  I did not understand it first time. You suggest I make Graphviz create an SVG file, and then parse SVG back to get the layout data? If that is your advice, then my counterargument would be - Graphviz supports much easier to parse formats, even json, with the layout data. That is what their documentation says. For some inexplicable reason json format was unavailable on my windows installation of Graphviz. But either way, parsing the output file seems backwards if there is a way to get the data from the core library itself, via pygraphviz.

Comment: @Michael  Yes, I chose SVG because it's XML, but there are others as I mention in my edited answer above.  I don't have the option in my version of GraphViz either to output to JSON, but there are numerous human-readable output formats.  It's just one tenable solution to your stated problem.

Comment: I have coded a parser for plain, but for some reason it did not give me all the items I needed - it did not give me the sements ( groups of nodes) IIRC. I will revisit it - it is a viable approach. However, I seem to have made some progress with pygraphviz, will continue this until either stuck or had it working. Will post the update here

Comment: I have voted this answer as accepted. However the problem with GraphVis persists on my machine. I think using GraphVis is risky. Unfortunately I found no better library/tool

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  Like you, I've wanted a superior tool for some time, but GraphViz is the best I've found that is free.

Answer (score 1):

**regarding Update 4**

it is still 2019 but this works perfectly for my needs

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.complete_graph(10)
pos = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
print(pos)
```

give me

```
{0: (327.0, 666.0), 1: (504.0, 594.0), 2: (327.0, 522.0), 3: (449.0, 450.0), 4: (283.0, 378.0), 5: (283.0, 306.0), 6: (473.0, 234.0), 7: (287.0, 162.0), 8: (418.0, 90.0), 9: (287.0, 18.0)}
```

a dict of nodes and positions!

Greets
dom

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.
It differs from Dominik Kummer's as it exposes the `pygraphviz.AGraph` object, making it possible to specify arbitrary gaphviz attributes to customize the layout.

```py
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv

g = nx.complete_graph(10)
ag = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(g)
ag.layout(prog='dot')
layout = [ag.get_node(n).attr['pos'] for n in ag.nodes()]
layout = [[int(ss) for ss in s.split(",")] for s in layout]
print(layout)
```

give me:

```
[[327, 666], [504, 594], [327, 522], [449, 450], [283, 378], [283, 306], [473, 234], [287, 162], [418, 90], [287, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

PyGraphviz doesn't have an API for retrieving and setting layout information such as node shapes, edge routing, etc.   I'm not aware of any Python interface to those parts of the Graphviz C library.  Graphviz itself does provide a Python interface including to the renderer but I don't think it does exactly what you want either - see http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gv.3python.pdf.

The simplest approach may indeed by generating SVG as @JHL suggests.