# Insert SVG file into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got 3 files: test.html, test.js and  test.svg

I'm trying to call the different files into HTML but the file svg don't work

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Using SVG as an object</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>


    <object data="test.svg" width="300" height="300"> </object>  <!-- Not working -->


    <input type="button" value="Start Animation" onclick="startAnimation();">
    <input type="button" value="Stop Animation" onclick="stopAnimation();"> 
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var timerFunction = null;

    function startAnimation() {
        if(timerFunction == null) {
            timerFunction = setInterval(animate, 20);
        }
    }

    function stopAnimation() {
        if(timerFunction != null){
            clearInterval(timerFunction);
            timerFunction = null;
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        var circle = document.getElementById("circle1");
        var x = circle.getAttribute("cx");
        var newX = 2 + parseInt(x);
        if(newX > 500) {
            newX = 20;
        }
        circle.setAttribute("cx", newX);
    }
```

test.svg

```
<svg width="500" height="100">
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
</svg>
```

I don't understand why I can't insert svg file with object

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would you need to use an object tag? Just use the svg directly. Originally this was used to run flash or something, it's not really needed nowadays.

Comment: Kindly take a look at this post for more insight [Link](https://vecta.io/blog/best-way-to-embed-svg)

Comment: So, it's better to use directly inside htm? Bcs imagine if i've got a lot of svg ?

Comment: Please check path to file and what did console say? Try to specify [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute in svg tag

Comment: Try an image tag. <img src="test.svg">. And check the console for errors.

Comment: your SVG file has no namespace defined i.e. no xmlns=... attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Answer (score 2):

[image]

See Dev.To Post: [<load-file> Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

---

Use a modern, native W3C standard Web Component `<load-svg>`

- it reads the SVG as text
- adds SVG to shadowDOM as DOM element
- **moves** the style element from *lightDOM* to *shadowDOM*
  So style is **only** applied to **one** SVG

```html
<load-svg shadowRoot src="//graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.svg">
  <style>
    svg { height:150px } text { stroke: green } path { stroke: red ; stroke-width:3 }
  </style>
</load-svg>
<load-svg src="//graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.svg">
<!-- all HTML here is overwritten -->
</load-svg>

<script>
  customElements.define('load-svg', class extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
      this.style.display = 'none'; // prevent FOUC (provided Custom Element is defined ASAP!)
      let src = this.getAttribute("src");
      let svg = await (await fetch(src)).text();
      if (this.hasAttribute("shadowRoot")) {
        this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = svg;
        this.shadowRoot.append(this.querySelector("style") || []);
      } else {
        this.innerHTML = svg;
      }
      this.style.display = 'inherit';
    }
  });
</script>
```

More complex example: [How to make an svg interactive to gather comments/annotations on depicted elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263255/how-to-make-an-svg-interactive-to-gather-comments-annotations-on-depicted-elemen/66385760#66385760)

Comment: I don't understand how come almost 2 years later, this answer doesn't have a trillion upvotes. I actually gave the first. This is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

`<object>` tags can be used on many elements, including SVG files, and therefore not recognized as image elements, So:

1. It's not available on image search. So you can use an `<img>` tag as fallback **(optional but recommended)**
2. You should specify the type of the object

So you can change it like this:

```
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg" width="300" height="300">
        <img src="test.svg" />
    </object>
```

And another problem is the SVG file. Based on [MDN documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) :

> The `xmlns` attribute is only required on the outermost SVG element of SVG documents. It is unnecessary for inner SVG elements or inside HTML documents.

so you need to add `xmlns` parameters to the SVG tag on SVG file like this :

```
<svg width="500" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
        style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
</svg>
```

I made a small simple example that works, checkout [this sandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-example-74nrz?file=/src/test.svg)

Comment: I updated the answer and also add a sandbox link that works, could you plz check it? @zefzefaa

Answer (score 0):

You can use svgs directly in the HTML. Easiest is to just use the SVG inside the HTML. You can also re-use an svg shape on a page but then the icons have a shadow-dom boundary.

If you use an object or svg tag, it will render just fine but you will lose all information about classes, IDs and so on in the SVG.

Further Information on [SVG on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

More information about how to [group and re-use shapes](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) in SVG on css-tricks ([and one more](https://css-tricks.com/pretty-good-svg-icon-system/), also on css-tricks)

```js
var timerFunction = null;

function startAnimation() {
  if (timerFunction == null) {
    timerFunction = setInterval(animate, 20);
  }
}

function stopAnimation() {
  if (timerFunction != null) {
    clearInterval(timerFunction);
    timerFunction = null;
  }
}

function animate() {
  var circle = document.getElementById("circle1");
  var x = circle.getAttribute("cx");
  var newX = 2 + parseInt(x);
  if (newX > 500) {
    newX = 20;
  }
  circle.setAttribute("cx", newX);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100">
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
</svg>

<input type="button" value="Start Animation" onclick="startAnimation();">
<input type="button" value="Stop Animation" onclick="stopAnimation();">
```