# SVG view element not showing content as expected

Tags: html, css, svg

According to this page [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/), the SVG `<view>` element...

> can actually wrap other elements, in which case that viewBox takes hold when the ID matches

However, I cant get it to work.

This is a simple SVG file:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" width="100" height="100"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <view id="one" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
  </view>
  <view id="two" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="green" />
  </view>
  <view id="three" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
  </view>
  <view id="four" viewBox="200 0 100 100" >
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="40" fill="yellow" />
  </view>
  <view id="five" viewBox="300 0 100 100" />
  <circle cx="350" cy="50" r="40" fill="cyan" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

This is the calling HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <style>
    img {border:1px solid #080;}
    img.red {content:url("foo.svg#one");}
    img.green {content:url("foo.svg#two");}
    img.blue {content:url("foo.svg#three");}
 </style>
</head><body>
  <img class="red" />
  <img class="green" />
  <img class="blue" />
  <img src="foo.svg#four" />
  <img src="foo.svg#five" />
</body></html>
```

The only circle actually shown is the cyan one. Anyone knows what is going on here?

Comment: view is not a container element and can't have rect children. You should stop reading that blog, it's not helping at all.

Comment: [Here's an accepted SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74911360/2015909) I gave last year on using SVG as an `<img>`. Follow the Codepen link in there for a much more elaborate example (the SVG can be found in the HTML tab from line #385). Let me know if you need more info...

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `<symbol>` elements `<view>` must not contain geometry/rendered elements.
That's why your first circle don't show up.

`<view>` elements are used to specify [predefined views](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/linking.html#ViewElement).
So you can pan a svg sprite sheet to a specific region via target ID - whereas you would otherwise no need to adjust background positions.

(To some extent you might compare them to HTML `<a>` anchor targets, helping you to jump to a specific section of a page)

The view element can only be used for sprite sheets with elements spread across the spritesheet area. Overlapping elements won't work.

In your case your first elements are overlapping.
A `<view>` doesn't change any visibility properties - so you'll see the topmost element. You can delete the `<view>` elements for these graphics

For overlapping elements we you can hide not targeted elements by CSS.

```
*[id] {
  display: none;
}
*:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a modified example svg:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<style>
/**
* show only targeted element
* as definded by fragment identifier
* e.g: sprite.svg#use_up_down
*/
    *[id] {
      display: none;
    }
    *:target {
      display: block;
    }
</style>

  <!-- displayed via fragment identifier -->
  <circle id="one" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
  <circle id="two" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="green" />
  <circle id="three" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
  
  <!-- displayed via view identifier-->
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="40" fill="yellow" />
  <view id="viewfour" viewBox="200 0 100 100" />
  
  <circle cx="350" cy="50" r="40" fill="cyan" />
  <view id="viewfive" viewBox="300 0 100 100" />

</svg>
```

Basically we're combining two fragment identifier techniques

- adjust the svg viewBox to `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` to match the desired 100x100 "icon" size.
- delete unnessecary view elements for overlapping assets
- add css rules to hide not targeted elements

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Overlapping target</h3>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100' height='100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle%3E%0A/**%0A* show only targeted element%0A* as definded by fragment identifier%0A* e.g: sprite.svg%23use_up_down%0A*/ *%5Bid%5D %7B display: none; %7D *:target %7B display: block; %7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3C!-- displayed via fragment identifier --%3E%3Ccircle id='one' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='red' /%3E%3Ccircle id='two' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='green' /%3E%3Ccircle id='three' cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='blue' /%3E%3C!-- displayed via view identifier--%3E%3Ccircle cx='250' cy='50' r='40' fill='yellow' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfour' viewBox='200 0 100 100' /%3E%3Ccircle cx='350' cy='50' r='40' fill='cyan' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfive' viewBox='300 0 100 100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E#one">

<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100' height='100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle%3E%0A/**%0A* show only targeted element%0A* as definded by fragment identifier%0A* e.g: sprite.svg%23use_up_down%0A*/ *%5Bid%5D %7B display: none; %7D *:target %7B display: block; %7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3C!-- displayed via fragment identifier --%3E%3Ccircle id='one' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='red' /%3E%3Ccircle id='two' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='green' /%3E%3Ccircle id='three' cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='blue' /%3E%3C!-- displayed via view identifier--%3E%3Ccircle cx='250' cy='50' r='40' fill='yellow' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfour' viewBox='200 0 100 100' /%3E%3Ccircle cx='350' cy='50' r='40' fill='cyan' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfive' viewBox='300 0 100 100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E#two">


<h3>View element - distributed positions</h3>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100' height='100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle%3E%0A/**%0A* show only targeted element%0A* as definded by fragment identifier%0A* e.g: sprite.svg%23use_up_down%0A*/ *%5Bid%5D %7B display: none; %7D *:target %7B display: block; %7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3C!-- displayed via fragment identifier --%3E%3Ccircle id='one' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='red' /%3E%3Ccircle id='two' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='green' /%3E%3Ccircle id='three' cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='blue' /%3E%3C!-- displayed via view identifier--%3E%3Ccircle cx='250' cy='50' r='40' fill='yellow' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfour' viewBox='200 0 100 100' /%3E%3Ccircle cx='350' cy='50' r='40' fill='cyan' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfive' viewBox='300 0 100 100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E#viewfour">

<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100' height='100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle%3E%0A/**%0A* show only targeted element%0A* as definded by fragment identifier%0A* e.g: sprite.svg%23use_up_down%0A*/ *%5Bid%5D %7B display: none; %7D *:target %7B display: block; %7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3C!-- displayed via fragment identifier --%3E%3Ccircle id='one' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='red' /%3E%3Ccircle id='two' cx='50' cy='50' r='50' fill='green' /%3E%3Ccircle id='three' cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='blue' /%3E%3C!-- displayed via view identifier--%3E%3Ccircle cx='250' cy='50' r='40' fill='yellow' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfour' viewBox='200 0 100 100' /%3E%3Ccircle cx='350' cy='50' r='40' fill='cyan' /%3E%3Cview id='viewfive' viewBox='300 0 100 100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E#viewfive">
```

#### Advantage of `<view>` spritesheets

Although the view concept seems to be very limited, the main advantage: you can easily edit all your sprites in a graphic editor as all items remain visible.

[image]
If you need to add a new icon: just place it next to the previous ones and define a new `<view>` area (illustrated by red boxes).

You can also compare alignment, size, stroke width and other visual properties at a glance to ensure consistent icon design.

Whereas when working with `<symbol>` or `<defs>` elements you need to unwrap the hidden icons to see them in your editor.

Drawbacks: you can't change any style properties like fill/stroke (just like any other image/background-image usage)

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen `<view>` work (the way I wanted it to work)

Every browser supports native Web Components to create HTML/SVG dynamically.
And *can* replace `<use>` and `<symbol>` with JS code.

```html
<svg-circle cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="red"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle cx="50"  cy="50"  fill="green"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle></svg-circle>
<svg-circle cx="100%" r="80" fill="blue"></svg-circle>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.style.display    = "inline-block";
      this.style.background = "beige";
      let cx   = this.getAttribute("cx")   || "50%";
      let cy   = this.getAttribute("cy")   || "50%";
      let r    = this.getAttribute("r")    || "45%";
      let fill = this.getAttribute("fill") || "hotpink";
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="100" height="100">` +
          `<circle cx="${cx}" cy="${cy}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}" />` +
          `<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40" fill="black" />` +
        `</svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That requires scripts. Most I know use skript-blockers anyway, so a website should work without any skripts.

Comment: Ah, the 2 percenters.. yes, modern technologies, React etc. etc. is all off the table then. https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/stats-no-javascript.html

Comment: Can you use this in all ways that you can use `<symbol>` or are there limitations?

Comment: It is JavaScript _creating_ SVG, So it can do anything JS and SVG can do. For the techies : note Web Components extend from HTMLElement only, you can not extend SVGElement itself.  Deep dives and documentation in my Dev.To posts: https://dev.to/dannyengelman